# php delete record using id

Tags: php, html, mysql

This program is meant to delete a record when given the id.

php:

```
if ($_GET['type']=="file"){

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "****";
    $password = "****";
    $dbname = "****";

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_error($conn)) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error($conn));
    }
    $sql = "SELECT id,user, FROM CreationsAndFiles WHERE id =".$_GET['id']." LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if ($row['user'] == $login_session){
        $sql = "DELETE FROM CreationsAndFiles WHERE id=".$_GET['id'];
        if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){echo "deleted";}
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
    //header("location: index.php?page=CreationsAndFiles");
}
```

the header is `type=file&id=9`
there is a record where `id=9`
It for no apparent reason will not work.

Comment: This statement, `if ($row['user'] == $login_session){ ...`, where did you define `$login_session`?

Comment: maybe you could add some `echo` statements throughout your `if` blocks, to see which path the execution is taking ?

Comment: @Dharman Fortunately this was 3 years ago and I've learned a lot more since then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL syntax is wrong;

```
SELECT id,user, FROM CreationsAndFiles...
              ^ extra comma
```

should be simply

```
SELECT id,user FROM CreationsAndFiles...
```

You may want to sanitize your input though, for example simply entering `type=file&id=id` will most likely do bad things.

Comment: it shouldn't do bad things unless the user was the person who uploaded it.

Comment: @DrevanTonder Yes, that is true, but  there are worse examples you could do by injecting SQL into the select and delete string. Unsanitized and un-parameterized data just inserted into an SQL statement can often cause major headaches.

Comment: Thanks I did not think of that.